# Postfix: Using sender dependent transport maps for redundancy and load balancing

Tags: postfix, load-balancing, redundancy

I have a Postfix server and I'm trying to use two different IPs in two different connections / ISPs to send email.

The address `89.xxx.xxx.2` is the default system gateway at `eth0` AND `188.xxx.xxx.2` is an address at `eth1` that has a dedicated routing table and custom `ip` rules (`ip rule add from 188.xxx.xxx.2 table SECONDARY` among others) to make routing possible. Both are able to route to the entire Internet, `ping`, `wget` and `postfix` are able to use both connections for outgoing traffic.

In `master.cf` I've defined the following:

```
out-one     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
  -o smtp_bind_address=89.xxx.xxx.2 
  -o inet_interfaces=89.xxx.xxx.2
  -o myhostname=outone.example.org
  -o smtp_helo_name=outone.example.org
  -o syslog_name=smtp-out-one
out-two     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
  -o smtp_bind_address=188.xxx.xxx.2
  -o inet_interfaces=188.xxx.xxx.2
  -o myhostname=outtwo.example.org
  -o smtp_helo_name=outtwo.example.org
  -o syslog_name=smtp-out-two
```

Now in `main.cf` I've added:

```
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = randmap:{out-one,out-two}
smtp_connection_cache_on_demand=no
```

When an email is submitted **Postfix will randomly pick one of the two transports and send the email. It works fine for load balancing** - Emails are sent using both addresses with the proper hostnames and all.

**Now let's say I take down `eth1`**. Postfix will still be able to send "half" of the emails via `eth0`/`89.xxx.xxx.2` but the other "half" will be will be queued:

```
postfix/smtp: fatal: parameter inet_interfaces: no local interface found for 188.xxx.xxx.2
```

**Is there a way for Postfix to try again with a different transport map if the previously chosen one isn't working**?

If `out-two` fails, call the randmap again > eventually dispatch the email using `out-one`. It seems like if I restart the server it will do it, but not on its own.

Why is it always retrying with the same transport unless restarted? Can this behavior be changed? Is there any other way to accomplish this kind of redundancy / load balancing?

Comment: In plus the random Postfix part, why do not add a route with lower weight ? If the link goes down, the route will push the network packets on the second interface, without intervention. "ip route  add 188.xxx.xxx.xxx/24 via eth0 metric 200 ; ip route  add 89.xxx.xxx.xxx/24 via eth1 metric 200". Do not forget the address translation too, or the packets will not come back

Comment: @Dom I might be missing the point, but I don't think network level priorities will fix this. Postfix has to bind to one of the two IPs to send an email. If the IP it picked is unavailable because the connection is down address translation and priorities won't save it. It would have initiate a new connection with a different hostname so spam filters won't complain...

Comment: As the NAT is working, the external users will only see the second IP address. It was one of the random used, so it must be correctely configured and the spam filters will not complain.

Comment: @Dom the problem is the content of the connection. Postfix will say "I'm outtwo.example.org" while connecting using an IP that has a different PTR resulting in issue.